# Drawing simple DNA helix

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to draw a simple schematic of a DNA helix. Using the sine function seems like a simple way, so here is what I have:
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[scale=.3, domain=0:14, samples=100]
        \foreach \x in {0,1, ...,14}{
            \tikzmath{
                \a = sin(\x r);
            }
            \draw[thick, gray] (\x,-\a) -- (\x,\a);
        }
        \draw[gray, very thick] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
        \draw[gray, very thick] plot (\x,{-sin(\x r)});
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have 4 visible vertical lines (base pairs) per loop of the helix (the fifth is obscured by the  crossing of the curves, see a 3d picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_double_helix#/media/File:Double_stranded_DNA_with_coloured_bases.png))
How can I accomplish that? Also any other suggestions as to how to approach this with TikZ are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

180/5=36, so

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[scale=.3, domain=0:15, samples=101]
        \foreach \x in {0,1, ...,14}{
          \draw[thick, gray] (\x,{-sin(\x*36)}) -- (\x,{sin(\x*36)});
        }
        \draw[gray, very thick] plot (\x,{sin(\x*36)});
        \draw[gray, very thick] plot (\x,{-sin(\x*36)});
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]